# Multer upload array handling response

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

How can we possibly accomplish this output or response from multer upload multiple file API?

This is my payload:

```
{
    "slides" : [
        {"_id":0,"text": "Description","src":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh..."},
        {"_id":1,"text": "Description","src":"data:image/png;base64,oTFKRtWHWKeSGJGGIGJ..."}
    ] 
}
```

This is the multer upload files API

```
router.post('/', upload.array('slides'), async (req, res) => {
    const payload = req.body;
    console.log(payload);
    // const newPayload = new Upload({slides: payload});   
    // const newPayload = new Payload({
    //     slides: payload
    // })
    // try {
    //     await newPayload.save();
    //     res.status(200).json(newPayload);
    // } catch (error) {
    //     res.status(400).json({ message: error.message })
    // }
});
```

Then I want the response result to be...

```
result:
{
    "slides" : [
        {"_id":0,"text": "Description","src":"file path.."},
        {"_id":1,"text": "Description","src":"file path.."}
    ] 
}
```

I need your help guys just new to node.js and practice some of the possible scenarios we may go through. Thanks a lot in advance :)